# Conversion with multiple steps in Java

Tags: java

I'm sorry if the title is misleading, but I am not really sure how else to describe it. I am trying to write a program in Java that would convert data, given only some of the conversion factors. For example, if I have these conversion factors:

- Convert a to b by multiplying a by 10
- Convert b to c by multiplying b by 20
- Convert c to a by dividing c by 200

How would I write a method that would convert a to c? I know that it would have to first convert a to b and then b to c but I do not know how to teach Java to recognize patterns like that. I know that I could just write if statements to check for these directly, however, I have a lot of these conversions and all those if statements seem terribly inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: how is it determined whether you need to convert from a->b, a->b->c, or c->a->b?

Comment: Why don't you just invert the rule from `c` to `a` ("multiply `a` by 200" instead of "divide `c` by 200"). That involves fewer steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a [Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)). Every arc between two nodes are a convertion. Finally, you need to run an algorithm like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest way to convert x to y.

This is a [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197418/where-can-i-get-a-java-implementation-of-dijkstras-algorithm), with answers providing links and implementation of Graphs and Dijkstra's algorithm in Java.

Edit: it seems somebody else has suggested the same idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can model this problem as graph search problem. Model each `a`, `b`, and `c`, into a node. Create a directed edge between node `u` and `v` if `u` can be converted into `v`.

Using this graph, you can find method to convert `x` to `y` by simply finding a path from `x` to `y`. You can use standard shortest path algorithm like Dijkstra algorithm to find such path.